# image resize to fit screen on mobile device using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to know if we can resize an image to fit the screen. Right now the image is suitable for iphone 5s, but it does not resize to another device or tablet to fit the screen.

I want to know if anyone has idea of how to resize to fit the screen.

This is my code.

```
<img alt="" src="images/main1.jpg" style="width:100%;height:auto;position:absolute;z-index:500"></img>
```

Comment: It is not recommended to resize on the client. Also create a jsfiddle.net when asking such questions - use lorempixel for example for images

Comment: it donot want to use lorempixel for my images as i have to use our own images..

Comment: I of course mean use lorempixel in the fiddle! you can use your own images in the jsfiddle.net too if you want

Comment: can you tell on which devices you tried?

Comment: hi.. i am using worklight mobile simulator. it comes with all devices..tablets and mobiles..

Answer (score 3):

What you want to do is to put the image inside a div whose width is set to be some percentage of the full screen width. This will always fit the image to be the width of the screen.

sample code:

```
<body>
    <div style="width: 100%;">
        <img alt="" src="images/main1.jpg" style="width: 100%;">
    </div>
</body>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5unWm/

Comment: hi..it is checking only width:100% in img element. try removing style in div.. it still works.. this approach works but does not fit all devices..